# can someone explain $A_\infty$ category and Fukaya category to me using plain words?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

Before I start, I have asked this question elsewhere so if seeing this question for the second time annoys you, I sincerely apologize.

I have been trying my best to understand $A_\infty$ category and Fukaya category by reading Wikipedia pages and short slides that can be found on google search. However, I could only comprehend a tiny portion of them and yet to know if my understandings were correct.

Can someone explain these two concepts to me using plain words that are easy to understand?

For example, geodesic curves are kind of the locally shortest path between two points on a surface. The tensor product of two vector spaces is isomorphic to the morphism set between two vector spaces.

I read some about morse homology already and learned floer homology is sort of the infinite version of morse homology. I think my problem is the intuition of $A_\infty$ category.

I am an undergrad in my senior year at a college in the US.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92356/a-infty-categories-basic-reference) seems relevant.

Comment: It would be great if you provided examples of what you do already think you understand, specifically, and gave examples of text from sources that you can’t understand (and you highlight the exact points of confusion). This will make your question more “answerable” and allow for answers that are more helpful for you

Comment: For the lagrangian side, you may try the early work of floer on lagrangian intersections